# How to Redirect to Profiles?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, jsx, react-router-dom

I want to redirect if someone clicks on Profile

```
<Link to="/">Home</Link>
<Link to="/profiles">Profiles</Link>
```

I tried using "Redirect" but when I load my page it defaults to "/profiles" rather than defaulting to "/" (sorry if someone else also asked the same question)

Here is my routing

```
<Router>
  <Navbar />
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/profiles">
      <Profile />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: If the link for the "/profiles" is clicked I would expect a navigation ***to*** "/profiles". But you are taking about when the page loads and some "default" route. I don't see an issue with your routes, what is the problem?

Comment: I want to redirect to "/profiles" without loading the existing Navbar (sorry for my bad explanations)

Comment: What does that mean? Where are you trying to redirect (`Redirect` component or `history.replace`)?

Comment: Redirect component

Comment: Do you want people to be redirected to "/" if someone clicks on Profiles using `<Link to="/profiles">Profiles</Link>` ? If yes, why is the profile component there in the Route? If a certain condition is required for redirection, you can use ternary operator to handle it inside the route (something like `redirectCondition ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Profile />` )

Comment: I want people to be re-directed to "/profiles" if someone clicks on "profile-link" without rendering the navbar on "/profiles" it should be like a new tab.

Comment: Links don't redirect, they navigate to pages. Is your `"/profile"` link ***not*** navigating to your `"/profile"` route? Are you wanting to open your app in a new window/tab?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it simple way using the **exact** in your profile route and add a redirect method on top of the route. Like this.

```
<Router>
  <Navbar />
  <Switch>
   {
      /* Redirect from root URL to /dashboard. */
      <Redirect exact from="/" to="/profiles" />
    }
    <Route path="/">
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/profiles">
      <Profile />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: The `exact` prop is completely unnecessary here. Also, removing it from the "/" home path without reordering the routes means only the "/" home path can ever be matched and rendered. "/profiles" wouldn't be reachable.

Comment: And now the "/" home page is unreachable if trying to hit exactly "/" (and no other non-profiles routes).

Comment: Yes because this condition if you get '/' in route so redirect to profile page so you need to add condition in routes or you can change home route '/' to '/home'.